# R Leaflet offline

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

In R I would like to build maps using the R [leaflet package](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/basemaps.html), however I would like it to work offline, as I have a demo that I would like to run, where there is no internet connection.

Using the standard line of R code below...

```
m <- leaflet() %>% setView(lng = -71.0589, lat = 42.3601, zoom = 12)
m %>% addTiles()
```

In the end, the map will go into a shiny app, so the solution needs to be compatible with that too.

I would like to be able to view the map offline, is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that it is possible if you care to download several terabytes of map tiles and store them offline. I'm not sure which is easier -- get the internet connection, or download the map tiles.

Answer (score 0):

You can serve your own tiles on your local machine using mapserver, so, it will work offline and you can carry as much as tiles you want (no by declaring it one by one) [Leaflet Mapserver](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Leaflet-OpenMap-Mapserver-WMS-td5164112.html)

other wise you can set as much cache as needed (you want)  To load the page in offline.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking to dynamically change the map, but produce a complete map with all the bells and whistles, then you can simply use R studio to export the html as a webpage.

You can pull a page up in your browser if you host it locally.

I have made some sizable html files this way and they work flawlessly. I even email them to other people and they work fine.